# Is there a difference between installing WhatsApp from exe file or Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-10, whatsapp

I was surprised to find out that you could install WhatsApp App for Windows 10 in 2 different ways. One by going to the WhatsApp website and downloading the exe file and installing. And the other by going to the Microsoft Store, searching for WhatsApp and installing.

Windows allows to install both on the same computer! Now, WhatsApp allows to make video/audio calls (beta version) from its WhatsApp App for Windows. But, downloading it and install it again from the Store, the beta version doesn't come up. Is there a way to get the beta version and if so, is it related to the way you install it?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find out the differences for the exact application. But in general, when it comes to the difference between traditional program(exe) and the one downloaded from windows store, it is about the different programing platforms they were used and the former application won’t ask for permission to access data associated with privacy settings in Windows 10 in the same way that a Microsoft Store app does.

Reference links:
Windows 10 desktop apps and privacy

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-desktop-apps-and-privacy-8b3b13bc-d8ff-5460-8423-7d5d5c1f6665

difference between app and program on windows 10

[difference between app and program on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1291125/difference-between-app-and-program-on-windows-10)

Comment: I am particularly interested with WhatsApp.